# How to use control+F to move right in Colaboratory Notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

I started using Colab notebook but I found out that it doesn't accept Control+F shortcut(On google chrome) to move right.
I sure deleted shortcut that was using control+F.

Still doesn't work.

Has anyone solved this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**: Now you can have it in a new version of editor.

---

I'm struggling with this as well on all machines that I tried. There is a [broader ticket on github's colab page](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/75).
As a temporarily workaround I'm applying my to-go swiss-knife [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) and make a custom shortcut for this.

For related issues (like 'B' for adding cell below, for instance) you can remap that in Tools -> Keyboard shortcuts.

Hope it helps.